# About the change of circle sector label text size

Tags: r

How can we easily change the text size of circle sector label in chordDiagram() of *circlize* package?

https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/advanced-usage-of-chorddiagram.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `par`

```r
library(circlize)

set.seed(999)
mat = matrix(sample(18, 18), 3, 6) 
rownames(mat) = paste0("S", 1:3)
colnames(mat) = paste0("E", 1:6)
mat
#>    E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6
#> S1  4 14 13 17  5  2
#> S2  7  1  6  8 12 15
#> S3  9 10  3 16 11 18

chordDiagram(mat)
```

[image]

```r
par(cex = 1.5)

chordDiagram(mat)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm not familiar. Is this largely a sankey / alluvial style of visualization? Also +1.

Comment: @Cole yes, I guess it's a bit like a Sankey with circular axes